# PostgreSQL 12 - foreign key on partitioning tables Error

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, partitioning

Reference V11
 - [PostgreSQL 11 foreign key on partitioning tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885368/postgresql-11-foreign-key-on-partitioning-tables)

Getting the similar error in V12 also.

Below is my test tables and PK and FK.

```
CREATE TABLE prod (id bigint NOT NULL, week bigint NOT NULL) PARTITION BY RANGE (week);
CREATE TABLE prod_w1 PARTITION OF prod FOR VALUES FROM (1) TO (2);
CREATE TABLE prod_w2 PARTITION OF prod FOR VALUES FROM (2) TO (3);
CREATE TABLE prod_w3 PARTITION OF prod FOR VALUES FROM (3) TO (4);
ALTER TABLE prod ADD CONSTRAINT xpk_prod PRIMARY KEY (id, week);
CREATE TABLE cust (id bigint NOT NULL, pid bigint Not NULL, week bigint NOT NULL) PARTITION BY RANGE (week);
CREATE TABLE cust_w1 PARTITION OF cust FOR VALUES FROM (1) TO (2);
CREATE TABLE cust_w2 PARTITION OF cust FOR VALUES FROM (2) TO (3);
CREATE TABLE cust_w3 PARTITION OF cust FOR VALUES FROM (3) TO (4);
ALTER TABLE cust ADD CONSTRAINT xpk_cust PRIMARY KEY (id, pid, week);
ALTER TABLE cust ADD CONSTRAINT xfk_cust FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES prod(pid) ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Here the last `ALTER TABLE` command is getting the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot reference partitioned table "prod"
```

Can you please check in V12 or in any patch and help me to get this error resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work in PostgreSQL v11, because foreign keys referencing partitioned tables are only supported from v12 on.

Your last statement also won't work in PostgreSQL v12, but for different reasons:

- There is no column `pid` in table `prod` (typo).
- The foreign key has to reference the whole unique or primary key in the target table, not just one of its columns.

This statement will work just fine in PostgreSQL v12:

```
ALTER TABLE cust
   ADD CONSTRAINT xfk_cust
      FOREIGN KEY (pid, week) REFERENCES prod(id, week)
      ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Comment: Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=43159a2657c6d741e164c72e142dfc7e

Comment: Very disappointing, I cannot believe that such half baked stuff makes into production. This is a serious limitation with a ton of use cases...I'm trying this workaround in out PG12 installation.

https://www.depesz.com/2019/04/24/waiting-for-postgresql-12-support-foreign-keys-that-reference-partitioned-tables/

Comment: @KevinParker No idea what you are talking about, but I guess it is not important, and you just want to vent steam.

Comment: Yes, it wastes weeks of my time on end because postgres needs so much hand holding to get working properly out of the box... The workaround at depesz worked and the foreign key constraints are maintained on the referencing tables.